# Exporting map as GeoTIFF in ArcMap - wrong coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, export, coordinates

I'm trying to export a map as a GeoTIFF but I'm facing an error as the map is being exported with a grey background as the sides. The problem is that the grey parts consist of coordinates, meaning that the coordinates are being expanded wrongly.
I  have tried to zoom in (and full extend) the area I'm interested in, but it seems that my ArcMap window does not recognised that (see grey zones in the image).

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Are you exporting from the map view or from a layout?  The latter would give you more control over many image properties including control over the extent.

Comment: I have tried both, but the result remains the same!